# opencv VideoCapture works in python command line but doesn't work in script

Tags: python, opencv

I have a simple script for capturing a frame from my mac's built-in camera. If I execute each line in the script from the python terminal, the code works perfectly and cap.read() returns ret==True and an image. However, if I put the exact same code in a script and run the script from the python command line, ret returns False and no image is captured.

I'm guessing that there is some environment variable that is set in the terminal that is somehow not set when I run the script, but I'm not sure how to go about figuring out what is wrong.

I'm running opencv 2.4.6.1 with MacOS 10.5.8 and Enthought python 2.7.2.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
print ret
```

Comment: I'm the same situation but Windows 10, python 3.9.7, opencv 4.5.3.